# Does my question really need to be welcome here?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, scope

Stack Overflow is great at enlightening people with things that really matter, and our hearts are grateful after all these recent years of light.  But it's definitely wasting huge potential by using this primitive type of selection by coercion.

Any question should be welcome here and there, because the focus should be on classifying and differentiating each one, and not on searching and destroying them.

I have chosen this platform to publish my beautifully crafted questions some years ago, after noticing so many curious people around, but after 5 minutes of fame, it was deleted. I felt really bad. It was my second question here, and I have never posted one since then.

My question is:

Why do you fight against what you could easily benefit from with a little bit of adapting and participating?

Comment: Why are you fighting against Stack Overflow’s policies (which I daresay have been shown to work pretty well) instead of adapting to *them*? And your only deleted question didn’t get five minutes of fame before getting deleted, it got five months.

Comment: Which question - hard to comment without seeing the details?

Comment: recommended reading: [Optimizing For Pearls, Not Sand](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) "...We feel that the world is awash in questions, but not answers. Answers are the real unit of work in any Q&A system. Therefore, the only logical thing to do is to maximize the happiness and enjoyment of answerers. If this means aggressively downvoting or closing unworthy and uninteresting questions, so be it. Without a community of people willing to answer questions, it really doesn’t matter if there are questions at all, does it?"

Comment: What happens when you allow every question under the sun: http://answers.yahoo.com

Comment: Your "primitive type of selection by coersion" is our "well honed set of rules and guidelines based on practical experience". If you have any convincing arguments against some of them or in favour of others, do let us know. But please be aware that there is a reason behind most of the specifics of this site.

Comment: By the way, I don't know what your specific question was, but if you have a hard time figuring out why it was closed/deleted, you can always ask. Perhaps understanding the why will help you see the logic as well.

Answer (score 11):

Staying on-topic by a strict definition is what makes Stack Overflow a useful site. As has been previously discussed, less-focused question-and-answer sites are rarely useful to future users, which is a goal of Stack Overflow.